# Как сделать, чтобы человек мог визуально добавлять дополнительные спаны в теме wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wp-theme, edit

Я создаю тему для wordpress (themeforest) и возникла проблема. Все заголовки темы имеют анимацию, где каждое слово выделено в отдельный спан и эти спаны появляются на 0.05с позже предыдущего. И нужна возможность, чтобы человек визуально мог добавлять дополнительные спаны. Без необходимости идти в код. Чтобы каждое написанное покупателем слово автоматически оборачивалось в спан, имея определенные настройки. И это слово появлялось на 0.05 позже предыдущего? Это можно как то реализовать в wordpress?

Я сделал образец этой анимации(смотрите на заголовки) http://bogdans-ultra-awesome-project-10773e.webflow.io

Comment: Всё можно сделать, в том числе и это. Страницу настроек в тему, шорткод в текст страницы в админке. Какие проблемы.

Comment: Я не понимаю как сделать этот шорткод. Ведь нужно чтобы слово самостоятельно заключалось в спан с необходимыми настройками положения и непрозрачностью. Да еще и с появилось на определенное время позже. Пожалуйста, дайте ориентир. Про страницу настроек - вы подразумеваете Customizer?

Comment: Текст внутри шорткода разбиваете по словам, каждое слово оборачиваете в программно в span, на каждый спан вешаете анимацию по какому-то алгоритму появления слов одно за другим.

Comment: Или можно сделать шорткод на одно слово - в параметрах шорткода можно указать любую анимацию, в шорткоде оборочиваете слово в спан и добавлете к нему анимацию.

Comment: Я бы например стилизовал один из тегов заголовка..

Comment: Стилизовали?  Не могли бы более подробно рассказать